# How do I add data from a join table to an existing model ASP/MVC/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got two tables, vendor and customer. I've got a third table linking these two that has vendor_ID and customer_ID. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, ASP and MVC. I built the model automatically using visual studio, so I've got simple vendor and customer objects with the getters and setters. I'd like to add another field to the VENDOR table, List customers. How can I populate this field for each vendor? At what stage in MVC are the objects/fields initialized?

Comment: What you are doing is mapping your models to the data objects in database. By doing so, you need to realize that the Vendor and Customer has many-to-many relation and each model needs to have a reference to each other. I.e. your Vendor model needs to have a property called CustomerList, type of IEnumberable<Customer> and similar property needs to be added in Customer model. And then you need to set the mapping rule (depends on the ORM tool you are using). Then your ORM tool will generate the data access functionalities for your MVC UI project.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.